# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1. Error - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm working on Android application and when trying to get SQLite database data as TextView (only one record in the table) facing this error.

The log and exception:

```
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tourinfo/com.example.tourinfo.TourInfo}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at com.example.tourinfo.TourInfo.onCreate(TourInfo.java:44)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-28 01:37:22.137: E/AndroidRuntime(9585):     ... 11 more
```

This is the java code:

```
public class TourInfo extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tour_info);

    TourInfoDatabaseHelper jobInfoDatabaseHelper = new TourInfoDatabaseHelper(this);



    Cursor cursorJObInfo = jobInfoDatabaseHelper.getAllJobInfoRecords();
    if(cursorJObInfo.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String startLocation = cursorJObInfo.getString(1);
            String endLocation = cursorJObInfo.getString(2);
            String type = cursorJObInfo.getString(3);
            Log.d("DB value", startLocation +" "+ endLocation +" "+ type);
        }while(cursorJObInfo.moveToNext());
    }


//  if(!cursorJObInfo.isClosed()){
//      cursorJObInfo.close();
 //   }
       TextView startLocationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_location_view);
        startLocationView.setText(cursorJObInfo.getString(1));
        TextView endLocationView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.end_location_view);
        endLocationView.setText(cursorJObInfo.getString(2));
        TextView typeOfJourneyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type_of_journey_view);
        typeOfJourneyView.setText(cursorJObInfo.getString(3));


}


public void onClickedLocations(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationList.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

}
```

TourInfoDatabaseHelper.java class

```
  public class TourInfoDatabaseHelper {

 // private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 2;
 // private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tourinfo.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tour_info_details";

public static final String JOBINFO_COLUMN_JOB_ID = "job_id";
public static final String JOBINFO_COLUMN_START_LOCATION = "start_location";
public static final String JOBINFO_COLUMN_END_LOCATION = "end_location";
public static final String JOBINFO_COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
public static final String JOBINFO_COLUMN_TOUR_NUMBER = "tour_number";
public static final String JOBINFO_COLUMN_USER_ID ="user_id";


private SQLiteDatabase jobInfoDatabase;
private JobInfoOpenHelper jobInfoOpenHelper;

public TourInfoDatabaseHelper (Context context) {
    jobInfoOpenHelper = new JobInfoOpenHelper(context);
    jobInfoDatabase = jobInfoOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
} 

public void saveJobInfoRecords (String startLocation,String endLocation,String type,String tourNumber,int userId){

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

//  contentValues.put(JOBINFO_COLUMN_JOB_ID, jobId);
    contentValues.put(JOBINFO_COLUMN_START_LOCATION, startLocation);
    contentValues.put(JOBINFO_COLUMN_END_LOCATION, endLocation);
    contentValues.put(JOBINFO_COLUMN_TYPE, type);
    contentValues.put(JOBINFO_COLUMN_TOUR_NUMBER, tourNumber);
    contentValues.put(JOBINFO_COLUMN_USER_ID, userId);

    jobInfoDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

}

public Cursor getAllJobInfoRecords(){
    return jobInfoDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
}

private class JobInfoOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    JobInfoOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,MainDBAdapter.DATABASE_NAME,null,MainDBAdapter.DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase jobInfoDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase jobInfoDatabase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //  jobInfoDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    //  onCreate(jobInfoDatabase);

    }

}


}
```

Please help me for avoid this error.

Comment: Can you please highlight **Line number 44** in  `TourInfo.java`

Comment: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1 , it means that the size of that array is 1 so use 0 instead of calling with 1

Comment: Have written the query to create table first ?

Comment: yes i created table and it had one tecord

Comment: @MAC line 44 is startLocationView.setText(cursorJObInfo.getString(1));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You loop through your cursor in the `do`-`while` loop but access cursor data with `getString()` after it, when the cursor is pointing after the last result row.

It's a little unclear what you want to do: You're fetching all records but are only using one result row. As a quick fix, capture the values inside the `do`-`while` and not after, e.g.

```
String startLocation = null;
String endLocation = null;
String type = null;

if(cursorJObInfo.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        startLocation = cursorJObInfo.getString(1);
        endLocation = cursorJObInfo.getString(2);
        type = cursorJObInfo.getString(3);
        Log.d("DB value", startLocation +" "+ endLocation +" "+ type);
    }while(cursorJObInfo.moveToNext());
}

// ...
startLocationView.setText(startLocation); // instead of calling getString() on the cursor here
// the same for the other textviews
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a similar error in the future, this is the cause of the problem:

You are resetting the index before checking whether the cursor is empty because `do..while` executes at least once before checking if the condition is satisfied.
to avoid this error, try `while...do` instead. You can even ignore the `do` part:

First check if the cursor is empty using `Cursor.geCount`

then move to the first record. Note: make sure you're not in the loop otherwise your will get into infinite loop.

then loop through the cursor using `while..do`

```
if(yourCursor.getCount()>0){
   yourCursor.moveToFirst();
   while(!yourCursor.isAfterLast()){
       startLocation = yourCursor.getString(1);
       endLocation = yourCursor.getString(2);
      yourCursor.moveToNext();
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check whether there is data available in the table.

This `Cursor cursorJObInfo = jobInfoDatabaseHelper.getAllJobInfoRecords();` is NULL because there is probably no data in the table.

Comment: table is created and it has one record